# MODX Revo getChildIds options

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

What is the `$options` parameter available for this method?

```
array getChildIds ([integer $id = null], [integer $depth = 10], [array $options = array()])
```

I am looking for a way to get all the children (depth=3) where the children's alias isn't "f".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
$id = 123;
$depth = 3;

$ids = $modx->getChildIds($id, $depth);
$docs = $modx->getCollection('modResource', array(
    'id:IN' => $ids
    ,'alias:!=' => 'f'
));
$output = '';
foreach ($docs as $doc) {
    $output .= $doc->get('pagetitle') . '<br/>';
}

return $output;
```

Comment: Great answer! But I have a question: When you use getCollection: isnt the result the complete objects with the content field?

Comment: I advise you to read this article - http://bobsguides.com/revolution-objects.html